# RecyclerView - bind the view holders again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

TL,DR : How can I force the recycler view to call the onBindViewHolder method again, at least for the visible items?

Calling notifyDataSetChanged() will make the list lag for some milliseconds, is there a better way?
Thanks.

I have a layout with an ImageView.
When ever bind is called for the imageview, I send a request to a server in order to get an image.
When the image is loaded, I save the bitmap in the ViewHolder , T variable.
And in the bind method I check if variable.getBitmap() is null or not, and if it is I will set the imageview.
Now If I scroll my list the images are going to be loaded, but If not, the imageviews are still blank, because onBindViewHolder wasn't called again.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I got you question correctly, but mb you're looking for `notifyItemChanged(int)`, which is much more precise than `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` is definitely the right way. Maybe `notifyItemChanged()` is even better because it only binds the selected item. If I get your question right, it seems that you do some things on the Main Thread which shouldn't be done there. Remember: Never do potential lengthy actions on the Main Thread, but always use something like `AsyncTask`.

I think it is a better approach to download the images asynchronously and then cache it, so you don't have to download it every time your `View`s are recycled. There are libraries for it.

While the images are loading you could show a `ProgressBar` or something else which signalizes the user, that the image is being loaded.

Comment: I also cache the images. Thank you. And I set a loading image to the imageview while loading.